# Why does my output stop halfway through the for-loop?

Tags: python-3.x, function, csv, python-requests

I want to download all the logos from this website. But if I run the code, the output varies. Sometimes it will download 5 logos, sometimes 10, but never all of them. What is wrong?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_csv('devclients.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(df)

clients = df['Clients'].tolist()

def clean_list(clients):
    for i in range(len(clients)):
        clients[i] = clients[i].lower()
        clients[i] = clients[i].replace(" ", "")
        clients[i] = clients[i].replace(".com", "")
        clients[i] = clients[i].replace("&", "")
    print(clients)
clean_list(clients)


def get_client_png(i):
    for i in range(len(clients[i])):
        URL = "https://logo.clearbit.com/{}.com".format(clients[i])
        print(clients[i])
        response = requests.get(URL)
        print(URL)
        open("{}.png".format(clients[i]), "wb").write(response.content)
        print(clients[i])
        i += 1
        print(clients[i])

get_client_png(i)
```

Comment: What is output of this script? Does it print out smth?

Comment: This shouldn't even work since `i` is not defined during the execution of `get_client_png(i)`. Do you run it in Jupyter? It holds the variables in memory, which may cause some problems for you here.

Comment: You should _not_ use `i` variable as both formal argument of the function `get_client_png` and loop variable in the same function.

Comment: Yeah it is ran in Jupyter, so that might be the problem. So I should replace `i` with what exactly?

Comment: @puf

['list of the company names']
aberdeen
https://logo.clearbit.com/aberdeen.com
aberdeen
abnamro
abnamro
https://logo.clearbit.com/abnamro.com
abnamro
aew
aew
https://logo.clearbit.com/aew.com
aew
altera
altera
https://logo.clearbit.com/altera.com
altera
apf
apf
https://logo.clearbit.com/apf.com
apf
arc
arc
https://logo.clearbit.com/arc.com
arc
aroundtown
aroundtown
https://logo.clearbit.com/aroundtown.com
aroundtown
arrowcapital
arrowcapital
https://logo.clearbit.com/arrowcapital.com
arrowcapital
aspen

Comment: @puf it also downloads the .png in the operating folder